# Object.prototype.__defineGetter__ (and __defineSetter__) polyfill

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, polyfills

I know the `__defineGetter__` (and `__defineSetter__`) method name is really [weird and deprecated](http://whereswalden.com/2010/04/16/more-spidermonkey-changes-ancient-esoteric-very-rarely-used-syntax-for-creating-getters-and-setters-is-being-removed/) but I find it more convenient than `Object.defineProperty`. Compare yourself:

```
//Readable
Something.prototype.__defineGetter__("name", function() {return this._name;});
//Uh... - what?
Object.defineProperty(Something.prototype, "name", {
                       get: function() {return this._name;}
                     });
```

Because, as I said, this method is being deprecated. So I'm creating a polyfill to put it back in bussiness:

```
if(!Object.prototype.__defineGetter__) {
  Object.prototype.__defineGetter__ = function(name, func) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
      get: func
    });
  }
}
```

It really just calls the standard `Object.defineProperty`. I could name the `__defineGetter__` whatever I wanted. I just decided to stick to something that already existed.

The problem here is that if I use `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` polyfills on the same property, I'm calling `Object.defineProperty` twice.

My question is: Is it OK to call `Object.defineProperty` twice on same property? Doesn't it overwrite something for example?

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite.

Comment: IMHO: that is why you use `.defineProperty` - you don't have to write separate methods for setter and getter.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Sometimes the setter isn't defined anyway. But my point is really that the `.defineProperty` is more capable but not very readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retain the old `set` or `get` when calling `defineProperty` again, you'll have to pull them out when adding the getter or setter:

```
var proto = Object.prototype;

proto.__defineGetter__ = proto.__defineGetter__ || function(name, func) {
    var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, name);
    var new_descriptor = { get: func, configurable: true};
    if (descriptor) {
        console.assert(descriptor.configurable, "Cannot set getter");
        if (descriptor.set) new_descriptor.set = descriptor.set; // COPY OLD SETTER
    }
    Object.defineProperty(this, name, new_descriptor);
};

proto.__defineSetter__ = proto.__defineSetter__ || function(name, func) {
    var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, name);
    var new_descriptor = { set: func, configurable: true};
    if (descriptor) {
        console.assert(descriptor.configurable, "Cannot set setter");
        if (descriptor.get) new_descriptor.get = descriptor.get; // COPY OLD GETTER
    }
    Object.defineProperty(this, name, new_descriptor);
};
```

Comment: It would be better adding `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` as non enumerable using `Object.defineProperty`. Otherwise it can be problematic in `for...in` loops.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't like using `defineProperty`, which is fine. However, then why even bother using `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__`? In my opinion, that looks even worse.

Back in March 2013 I had the same problem with emetic code, which is why I cooked up a [simple 41 LOC micro-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dictionary) which you can install via the command:

```sh
npm install dictionary
```

Using this micro library you can define getters and setters like this instead:

```
Something.prototype.define({
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    },
    set name(_name) {
        this._name = _name;
    }
});
```

In addition it also allows you to create non-enumerable, non-deletable and constant properties easily. Read the documentation for more details.

If you don't want these additional features then just use:

```
Object.prototype.define = function (properties) {
    if (Object.isExtensible(this)) {
        var ownDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor;
        var defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
        var keys = Object.keys(properties);
        var length = keys.length;
        var index = 0;

        while (index < length) {
            var key = keys[index++];
            var descriptor = ownDescriptor(properties, key);
            defineProperty(this, key, descriptor);
        }
    }
};
```

Hope that helps.