# Override a setter, and the getter must also be overridden

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, getter-setter, traceur

```
class AbstractClass {

    constructor() {
    }

    set property(value) {
        this.property_ = value;
    }

    get property() {
        return this.property_;
    }

}

class Subclass extends AbstractClass {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    set property(value) {
        super.property = value;
        if (!(this.property_ instanceof SubclassAssociatedClass)) throw new TypeError();
    }

    //get property() {
    //  return super.property;
    //}

}
```

Override the `set` method of an attribute and it appears the `get` method must be overridden also, otherwise `undefined` is returned (i.e., the `get` method is not inherited, uncomment the subclass `get property()` method above and everything works fine).

I assume this is a part of the spec., it would follow though possibly if the behaviour was a consequence of cross compiling.  Just to be sure, is this the correct way to code overridden setters and getters (both at the same time or not at all)?

Comment: Can you edit your example so that the setter/getter is not just calling super?

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400010/object-prototype-definegetter-and-definesetter-polyfill/27400162#27400162. It discusses the problem in terms of `__defineGetter__` etc., but the principle is the same: if you are defining/redefining the setter on a property that already has a getter, you need to retrieve the getter and reset it along with the setter.

Comment: Just found this out the hard way, today.  I was wondering why several of my properties became write-only ;-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional (a part of the spec). If an object has an own property (`.property` in your example), this property will be used and not an inherited one. If that property is existent, but is an accessor property without a getter, then `undefined` will be returned.

Notice that this behaviour has not changed from ES5.

Comment: Switched to CoffeeScript about the same time as ES5, prior to that `.__defineGetter__()` / setter was never going to be standardised.

Comment: @Bergi Out of curiosity, if you could point to the part of the spec that states this, I'd be grateful. I tried searching both the ES5 and ES6 specs but neither of them seem to explicitly state anything about overriding getters or setters.

Comment: @brianpeiris: The "overriding" happens in [`[[DefineOwnProperty]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-defineownproperty-p-desc), which is called from [literal property definitions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation) or through [`Object.defineProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.defineproperty) (ES5 works basically the same, though the respective spec sections may be easier to read)

Comment: @brianpeiris: And then when evaluating property access or assignment, [\[\[Get\]\]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver) and [\[\[Set\]\]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver) are relevant, which both use [\[\[GetOwnPoperty\]\]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-getownproperty-p) that doesn't care whether setter and getter or only one of them is defined.

Comment: Is this still correct? Can you please link the spec defining it?

Comment: @CSchulz Yes. This hasn't changed since ES6 (linked in the above comments), you'll find the same in the current spec.