# B extends A: set in B will overwrite get

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

TypeScript: [view on playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%09protected%20_name%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%09%0A%09set%20name(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%09%09this._name%20%3D%20name%0A%09%7D%09%0A%09get%20name()%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this._name%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0A%09protected%20_name%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%09%0A%09set%20name(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%09%09this._name%20%3D%20name%20%2B%20%22B%22%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

```
class A {
    protected _name: string = ""

    set name(name: string) {
        this._name = name
    }   
    get name() {
        return this._name
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected _name: string = ""

    set name(name: string) {
        this._name = name + "B"
    }
}
```

In the compiled class B this will overwrite the definition of the `set` AND `get`:

```
Object.defineProperty(B.prototype, "name", {
    set: function (name) {
        this._name = name + "B";
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

The result is, that `get name` does not work anymore on class B:

```
let b = new B()
b.name = "test"
console.log(b.name) // undefined
```

Is there a way to inherit the getter from class A?

Comment: Unfortunately it is the `name` that you are overriding, not the specific getter/setter. You could do `get name(){ return super.name; }` though. Would that be enough in your case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override a setter, and the getter must also be overridden](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28950760/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

The below code works in the TypeScript compiler, without any errors:

```
class A {
   protected _name: string = ""

   set name(name: string) {
       this._name = name
   }   
   get name() {
       return this._name
   }
}

class B extends A {
   // Removed _name declaration here

   set name(name: string) {
       super["name"] = name + "B"      // <=== Using super here
   }
   get name() {
       return super["name"]            // <=== And here
   }
}

var b = new B();
b.name = "foo";
console.log(b.name); // "fooB"
```

The only difference from @Crowder's code is that instead of `super.name` I'm using `super["name"]`. If you use `super.name` the compiler will issue this error: `Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword`. Please note: TypeScript still compiles when it finds errors, so using `super.name` also works, notwithstanding the errors.

Comment: Sounds like your `name` property in `A` was declared private by accident. There's no reason to use bracket notation for static property names, rather you should fix the reason of the compiler error (warning).

Comment: @Bergi: `name` is not private. The compiler is complaining because only public and protected METHODS of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword, and `name` is not a METHOD. The bracket notation is, of course, only a hack, to bypass the compiler warning, since `super.name` also works.

Comment: Have you tried reporting this as a bug to typescript? All properties, not only methods, should be available via `super`.

Comment: I haven't. The error message is very clear that only methods are allowed, and it behaves like that, so I assumed it's the expected behavior. Can you tell me where it says all properties, not only methods, should be available via super?

Comment: I don't know where or whether is says something, and what exactly. But it clearly should be changed, in the compiler and possibly in the spec if necessary. This hack should not be required to suppress this error.

Comment: Thank you @MarcG, this should be the accepted answer : )